# Manage tasks in Azure DevOps when using Kanban boards

Tags: azure-devops, kanban, azure-boards

When using Kanban boards in Azure DevOps, if the story is split into tasks, is there any support for working with tasks?

In the below image we can see the tasks with yellow under the stories but that is not easy for the developers to use. The task board can only be used if also working with sprints.

I haven't been able to find any documentation related to this. Are tasks supposed to be used at all when using a Kanban board?

[image]

Comment: Can I know how's the status on this? Did you has any other puzzle or confusing on my explanation? Free to comment below:-)

Answer (score 0):

> Are tasks supposed to be used at all when using a Kanban board?

No, I'm afraid there's no such feature supported in azure devops boards now.

Because this is by designed based on the concept of `Agile` process.

See this [Agile process workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/agile-process-workflow?view=azure-devops):

[image]

For `Epic`, `Feature` and `Stories`, they are all belong to **Portfolio backlogs**, while tasks is **iteration backlog**.

For our Azure devops Kanban Boards, it used to display the **Portfolio backlogs** for management team. You could [add additional customized portfolio backlogs level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/set-up-your-backlog?view=azure-devops) by modifying the process your project is using.

But you could not change the `tasks` from **iteration backlog** to **Portfolio backlogs**. Because this does not match the basic concept of Agile process.

Comment: What is the iteration backlog? Is there a view for that?

Comment: @MathiasRönnlund, sorry for my late reply. Please go organization setting-> process-> the process that the project is using-> Backlog levels tab. https://imgur.com/a/z99TzXc

Comment: When someone's view of "process" gets in the way of people actually wanting to use the product in the way that _their_ process works. :|  Why have these preconceived notions of a particular methodology in the first place? It's fine to have sensible defaults that guide newer users, but in the end, people work how _they_ want to work, not how _you_ want them to work. :(

Answer (score 0):

For Azure DevOps **Boards**, the **Boards** view visualizes the **Requirement Backlog** which is typically a **User Story** or **Product Backlog Item**, but it is not meant for moving **Task** states. For moving a **Task** between states, the **Sprints** view is used:

[image: Snippet showing the Sprints view in Azure DevOps Boards]

In my experience, for a team using an iterative methodology like **Scrum** or the **Agile** template, the **Sprints** view is likely more heavily used than **Boards** and the opposite is likely normal for a team using **Kanban** since **Boards** visualizes the requirements nicely for flow. Hybrid methodologies like **ScrumBan** could use both. Whatever works best for the team.

See this table and more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/backlogs-boards-plans?view=azure-devops):
[image: Snippet of table showing Azure DevOps views for work item types]

Comment: The question is that if using Kanban without sprints but the story would involve two people to implement, how should they split their work? Because using tasks doesn't seem so easy to use.

Comment: @MathiasRönnlund In that case, could you split the Story into a smaller increment to be worked by each person?